# Angular ng-repeat - unique $index across multiple loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im using ng-repeat to loops through an array of objects for which I would like to print numbered headings.

For example:

**Controller**

```
var cars = [
    {make:'ford',model:'mustang'},
    {make:'ford',model:'fusion'},
    {make:'bwm',model:'x5'},
    {make:'honda',model:'civic'},
    {make:'honda',model:'accord'},
    {make:'toyota',model:'camry'},
    {make:'honda',model:'crv'},
];
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-show="car.make=='ford'">
    <h1>Fords:</h1>
    <div><b>{{$index}})</b> {{car.model}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-show="car.make=='honda'">
    <h1>Hondas:</h1>
    <div><b>{{$index}})</b> {{car.model}}</div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output**

```
Fords:
0) mustang
1) fusion

Hondas:
0) civic
1) accord
2) crv
```

**Actual Output**

```
Fords:
0) mustang
1) fusion

Hondas:
3) civic
4) accord
6) crv
```

In other words, within each loop $index maintains a reference to that of the source array. Which I guess makes sense but I thought the purpose of $index was to count iterations within the scope of a given loop?

How can I use $index (or something else) to achieve my **Expected Output**?

Comment: That's happening because your expected o/p doesn't go with working principal of `$index`.index will print the actual index of element in array.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to create a filtered array which will only return the matching elements.Then you can use `$index` correctly to print the ordering numbers.

```
<body ng-app="textInputExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('textInputExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var cars = [{
          make: 'ford',
          model: 'mustang'
        }, {
          make: 'ford',
          model: 'fusion'
        }, {
          make: 'bwm',
          model: 'x5'
        }, {
          make: 'honda',
          model: 'civic'
        }, {
          make: 'honda',
          model: 'accord'
        }, {
          make: 'toyota',
          model: 'camry'
        }, {
          make: 'honda',
          model: 'crv'
        }, ];
        $scope.cars = cars;
        $scope.filteredcars = function(make){
           return $scope.cars.filter(function(e) { return e.make === make });
        };

      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="car in filteredcars('honda')">
      <h1>Hondas:</h1>
      <div><b>{{$index}})</b> {{car.model}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below by making `orderBy` of `make` prop. Its not rigid solution. Further you could make use custom `filter` create a new collection of grouped object by `make` property.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy: 'make'">
    <h1 ng-if="cars[$index].make != cars[$index-1].make">
       {{car.make}}:
    </h1>
    <div><b>{{$index + 1}})</b> {{car.model}}</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3xb0KHBv8z3y80S2NWAo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/mmghori/L6cQN/647/) here.

## VIEW:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Main">
  <div ng-repeat="carPerMake in carsToFilter() | filter:filterMake">
    <b>{{carPerMake.make}}:</b>
    <div ng-repeat="car in cars | filter:{make: carPerMake.make}"> {{$index}} - {{car.model}}</div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Controller:

```
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.cars = [{
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'mustang'
  }, {
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'fusion'
  }, {
    make: 'bwm',
    model: 'x5'
  }, {
    make: 'honda',
    model: 'civic'
  }, {
    make: 'honda',
    model: 'accord'
  }, {
    make: 'toyota',
    model: 'camry'
  }, {
    make: 'honda',
    model: 'crv'
  }, ];

  var makeArr = [];

  $scope.carsToFilter = function() {
    makeArr = [];
    return $scope.cars;
  }

  $scope.filterMake = function(car) {
    var newMake = makeArr.indexOf(car.make) == -1;
    if (newMake) {
      makeArr.push(car.make);
    }
    return newMake;
  }
}
```

## Output:

ford:
0 - mustang
1 - fusion

bwm:
0 - x5

honda:
0 - civic
1 - accord
2 - crv

toyota:
0 - camry